# How to increase font-size of all divs of a certain class

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, selection

I want to provide the users of my webpage a simple way to increase and decrease the text size of all the elements which belong to `class="txt"`. The two buttons in the snippet below should decrease / increase the font-size by 4pt every time they are clicked (a slider would also suffice).

I've done a lot of research and tried different methods ([1](https://davidwalsh.name/change-text-size-onclick-with-javascript), [2](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-make-text-bigger-with-js-via-onclick/226189), [3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/allow-users-to-change-font-size-of-a-webpage-using-javascript/)) but I wasn't able to make any of them work. These solutions act on the `id` of the elements, so I tried to replace *getElement**ById**('txt')* with *getElement**sByClassName**('txt')*; still nothing.

```css
.txt {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

summary {
  font-size: 20pt;
}

/* STYLE */ .txt, summary { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre-wrap; }
/* STYLE */ .zoombox { display: flex; padding: 8pt 0pt; }
```

```html
<div class="zoombox">
  <button class="btn zoom out">-</button>
  <div class="txt"> ZOOM </div>
  <button class="btn zoom in">+</button>
</div>

<details open>
  <summary>TITLE OF THE SONG</summary>
  <div class="txt chords">  Em   F        D#    </div>
  <div class="txt lyrics">A song with its lyrics</div>
</details>
```

Comment: Please include your script as well!

Comment: At the time of posting I wanted to it but I didn't know where to start (bc I had no understanding of the subject). Now the answers confirm to me I was on a totally different path. I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, I did my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to get the current font-size (as a string with a unit of measure). Then I would suggest to *multiply* this number with a coefficient and then append the *same* unit again to it. This coefficient could be 1.1 or 0.9 for a 10% increase or decrease.

Here is your HTML with that solution added:

```js
document.querySelector("button.in").addEventListener("click", () => zoom(1.1));
document.querySelector("button.out").addEventListener("click", () => zoom(0.9));

function zoom(coeff) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".txt, summary").forEach(el => {
        let css = getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("font-size");
        let size = parseFloat(css);
        let unit = css.replace(/[\d.-]*/, "");
        el.style.fontSize = size * coeff + unit;
    });
}
```

```css
summary { font-size: 20pt }
.txt { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre-wrap; font-size: 14pt }
.zoombox { display: flex; padding: 8pt 0pt }
```

```html
<div class="zoombox">
  <button class="btn zoom out">-</button>
  <div class="txt"> ZOOM </div>
  <button class="btn zoom in">+</button>
</div>

<details open>
  <summary>TITLE OF THE SONG</summary>
  <div class="txt chords">  Em   F        D#    </div>
  <div class="txt lyrics">A song with its lyrics</div>
</details>
```

Comment: This is the best solution I received so far, TY. I updated the snipped (probably while you were working on the solution), do you happen to also know what's the js selector for the `summary` element?

Comment: The selector for an element name is the simplest possible: just that name: `document.querySelector("summary")`

Comment: I said that poorly, I wanted to select all the summaries. I solved it by doubling the code inside `function zoom(coeff)` and replacing `.txt` with `summary` in the second iteration. I tried to combine the selection to avoid doubling the code, but I was unsuccessful (for now). -- I also tried a third iteration to scale the `padding-top` of `lyrics`, but that seems to overwrite the increase of `font-size` of `.lyrics`... Do you know why?

Comment: You can combine selectors in a comma-separated list. Updated my answer to also select `summary` elements. As to your second question, that seems to go beyond the question on this page. If you have a problem with setting the padding independently, then consider asking a new question.

Comment: The problem I had was a typo, everything works. Question closed

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. You would be setting an event listener on the body, but click events bubble so that single event listener will catch clicks on any children.

This approach prevents the zoom buttons from also scaling.

```js
let zoomIn = document.getElementById('zoomIn');
let zoomOut = document.getElementById('zoomOut');
let textArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('txt'));

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', zoom);

function zoom(e) {
  textArray.forEach(txt => {
    let currentSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(txt).fontSize);
    if(e.target.classList.contains('in')) {
        txt.style.fontSize = (currentSize + 1) + 'px';
    }
    else {
        txt.style.fontSize = (currentSize - 1) + 'px';
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.txt {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

summary {
  font-size: 20pt;
}

/* STYLE */ .txt, summary { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre-wrap; }
/* STYLE */ .zoombox { display: flex; padding: 8pt 0pt; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="zoombox">
    <button id="zoomOut" class="btn zoom out">-</button>
    <div class="txt"> ZOOM </div>
    <button id="zoomIn" class="btn zoom in">+</button>
  </div>

  <div class="txt titles">TITLE OF THE SONG</div>
  <div class="txt chords">  Em   F        D#    </div>
  <div class="txt lyrics">A song with its lyrics</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step over the array**

`getElementById('txt')` will return a single element; `getElementsByClassName('txt')` will return an array. You would need to step through the elements and change the font size.

Here's a working sample: https://jsbin.com/mozobik/edit?html,output

Comment: Ooh, that's why! -- Your code is not what I needed (it sets a fixed value instead of increasing it), but your explanation and your code teach me something new!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should format your `html` code. I suggest you to have your html classes formatted like the code given below.

```js
const val = document.querySelectorAll(".txt");
const zoomin = document.querySelector(".zoom-in");
const zoomout = document.querySelector(".zoom-out");

function zoom_in() {
  val.forEach((element) => {
    const fonsi = window
      .getComputedStyle(element, null)
      .getPropertyValue("font-size");
    const currentSize = parseFloat(fonsi);
    element.style.fontSize = currentSize + 1 + "px";
  });
}

zoomin.addEventListener("click", () => {
  zoom_in();
});
```

```html
<div class="zoombox">
    <button class="btn zoom-out">-</button>
    <div class="txt"> ZOOM </div>
    <button class="btn zoom-in">+</button>
</div>
      
<div class="txt titles">TITLE OF THE SONG</div>
<div class="txt chords">  Em   F        D#    </div>
<div class="txt lyrics">A song with its lyrics</div>
```

And you can write a zoom-out function based on the `zoom_in` function.

Comment: I originally kept _zoom_ separate from _in_ / _out_ , to use it as a single CSS selector, but I'll follow your advice (and use _.zoom-in, .zoom-out_ as a selector)

Comment: You can use the BEM model to format your CSS classes. https://www.devbridge.com/articles/implementing-clean-css-bem-method/#:~:text=What%20is%20BEM%3F,by%20following%20some%20simple%20rules.

Comment: Huge! I found it accidentally years ago, but was unable to find it again when I started coding (last month). Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

this example can help you to find your answer read this code carefully special javascript part:

```js
    function iWChangeEveryThing(){
      const fontSize = document.getElementById("numberr").value;
      const prag = document.getElementById("prag").style;
      prag.fontSize = fontSize + "px"
    }
```

```css
    body{
      text-align: center;
    }
    button{
      font-size: 30px;
      padding: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="numberr">
    <p id="prag">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, veritatis. Quaerat nam eos aspernatur nisi deserunt enim. Quam corrupti asperiores cupiditate recusandae aliquid at nisi quisquam quidem. Unde, dolor esse.</p>
    <button onclick="iWChangeEveryThing()">click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'll implement it and also I use px instead pt

```js
const zoomOut = document.querySelector(".zoom__out");
const zoomIn = document.querySelector(".zoom__in");
const texts = document.querySelectorAll(".txt");

// whatever size you want as default
let curFontSize = 14;

zoomOut.addEventListener("click", function () {
  curFontSize -= 4;
  texts.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.fontSize = `${curFontSize}px`;
  });
});

zoomIn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  curFontSize += 4;
  texts.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.fontSize = `${curFontSize}px`;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="zoombox">
  <button class="btn zoom out">-</button>
  <div class="txt"> ZOOM </div>
  <button class="btn zoom in">+</button>
</div>

<details open>
  <summary>TITLE OF THE SONG</summary>
  <div class="txt chords">  Em   F        D#    </div>
  <div class="txt lyrics">A song with its lyrics</div>
</details>
```

Comment: I added the html and made a runnable snippet from your code. There are Javascript errors when executed.

Comment: `.zoom__out` and `.zoom__in` should be `.zoom.out` and `.zoom.in`